# Emulator proxy port 3042 not working in disconnected mode using sitecore JSS CLI

Tags: jss, sitecore-cli, react

I have installed the latest `JSS CLI V21.7.0`, after the `'jss start'` command the Sitecore contents are displayed using the port `'http://localhost:3000'`. But I want to create and configure `scjssconfig.json` file inside my reactJS application for that I need the API key and secret key which needs to be created in the emulator proxy port 'http://localhost:3042', which is not working though the port is successfully running without any firewall restrictions.

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "layoutServiceHost": "http://localhost:3042",
    "apiKey": "<YOUR_API_KEY>",
    "deploySecret": "<YOUR_DEPLOY_SECRET>"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

- Node version: v18.7.0
- npm version: 8.15.0

[image: scaffolding messages while jss start command is running]

[image: Error displayed on proxy port]